# Fat-Free Framework; SQL Mapper inserts twice

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

Weird problem with F3's SQL Mapper raised when I tried to build myself a framework based on it.

When I try to insert row into MySQL database, it get's inserted twice. I've made the simpliest debug by putting echo in `beforeinsert` method, which is triggered **once**. So... what am I doing wrong that causes rows to get doubled?

Controller (specific code):

```
$faq = new \FaqModel();
$faq->question = $params['q'];
$faq->answer = $params['a'];
$faq->save();
$id = $faq->get('_id');
if (isset($id))
    $this->status = 'success'; // this is shown
else
    $this->status = 'nope, not working';
```

FaqModel.php (yup, nothing here)

```
class FaqModel extends \BaseModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('faq');
    }
}
```

BaseModel.php (i thought here, but `beforeinsert()` is called once):

```
abstract class BaseModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper
{
    public function __construct($table)
    {
        $f3 = \Base::instance();
        $this->db=new \DB\SQL(
            'mysql:host='.$f3->get('db_host').';port='.$f3->get('db_port').';dbname='.$f3->get('db_name'),
            $f3->get('db_user'),$f3->get('db_pass'));
        parent::__construct($this->db,DB_PREFIX.$table);
        $this->table = DB_PREFIX.$table;
        $this->beforeinsert(function($me) {
            echo 'before insert <br/>';
            $me->createdAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        });
        echo 'construct <br/>';
    }
    // some loading methods here not related to problem
}
```

output is simple:

```
construct
before insert
success
```

and no redirects shown in websniffers. But still I get my database duplicated rows.

---

## Edit:

Okay, now it's weirder than it was. I executed two add request in a row. What happened is:

1) on first request, two rows were added:

```
41  testing         db_testing  2015-02-13 09:08:21     2015-02-13 09:08:21
42  testing         db_testing  2015-02-13 09:08:21     2015-02-13 09:08:21
```

2) on second request, **three** rows were added:

```
43  testing         db_testing  2015-02-13 09:10:53     2015-02-13 09:10:53
44  another_test    db_why      2015-02-13 09:11:04     2015-02-13 09:11:04
45  another_test    db_why      2015-02-13 09:11:05     2015-02-13 09:11:05
```

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I don't think the hook is guilty here but you can try to remove it and see if it helps. Also you can `echo $faq->db->log()` right after saving to see the list of executed SQL statements. Another idea: no trigger defined at DB level?

Comment: @xfra35 It showed me three inserts, each one prepended with `SHOW columns FROM` and appended with `SELECT .... WHERE id = 31`. Each one shows same `id`. Anyway, now it has been added three times to the DB with `id` = 31, 32 and 33. 

On the DB I haven't added anything I can think of being guilty. Only one field (`updatedAt`) is set to autoupdate on update.

Comment: @xfra35 Now It's weird. more data on question edit

Comment: I don't think there is ever 3 added at once. Look at the timestamps and the data

Comment: Can't see what's wrong with your code, try xdebug or any other debugger and check the flow step-by-step.

Comment: No cache here? Check the value of `CACHE`. Also switch to a POST request and see if it helps (it's not safe to use GET for DB write).

Answer (score 1):

What about your routing to this specific controller? Could it be that you do this on a GET request? Some browsers send an additional HEAD request right before the actual GET request. The framework automatically handles that, calls your GET controller, inserts the row once, and cut down the response to the header only. Then comes the GET request, which does everything again, resulting in a 2nd row. That would explain your apps behavior.

If so, you could add a check and see if the F3 `VERB` var contains `GET` to get around the HEAD request.

Comment: Yes, I did it on GET request, I had no idea that it can be sent twice. But anyway, I've tried to check with `if ($f3->get('VERB') == 'GET')` but still done twice. It seems to be double-get

I will in later change it to POST request, but now I want to resolve the problem with GET since I probably will do some (mainly statistical) inserts with GET requests

Comment: Make sure you send back no-cache headers for proxies or you might find that your number of inserts goes down to zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but, fwiw, I suspect the problem the OP had was to not issue a mapper reset() call after each save. Technically, I think the behavior of the mapper object, if you don't reset it, is 'undefined' but it makes a bit of sense that the mapper would remember the last record and, sort of, tack the new record on after it.

At any rate, best practice for F3 mapper is to either instantiate a new mapper or to issue a reset between db calls. I can't speak to the performance trade-off except to assume that reset() whatever it does do would have to be cheaper than standing up a whole new object.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to call `reset()` immediately you instantiating your class.

**Best Practices**

- Instantiate your DB outside your model then call `parent::__construct($db,'faq')`.
- create your trigger outside the construct

  `function addCreated() {
          echo 'before insert <br/>';
          $this->createdAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      }`
- Add your triggers as `$this->beforeinsert([$this,'addCreated']);`

The full base is now:

    `abstract class BaseModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper
    {
        public function __construct($table)
        {
            $f3 = \Base::instance();
            $db = $f3->get('db')
           parent::__construct($db,DB_PREFIX.$table)
           $this->beforeinsert([$this,'addCreated']);
            echo 'construct <br/>';
        }
        // some loading methods here not related to problem
    }`